# Why Python can not find an existing file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just started with python, and following the [**[Tutor] how to simply run a .py file**](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2004-July/030634.html) I am executing this command to run a python code that I found online:

[image]

So the picture is my file on a Windows desktop and the cmd window. Can anyone please show me what is the problem? Please and thanks

Comment: Did you mistype the file name? What happens when you run `dir C:\Users\kkhalaf\Desktop\test.py`?

Comment: @NPE https://s24.postimg.org/go4tcuu6t/image.png this way?

Comment: try `dir C:\Users\kkhalaf\Desktop\` see if yoy actually have the test.py in Desktop or in Downloads or Documents folder..

Comment: @SandraK: Yes. This demonstrates conclusively that the file you're trying to run does not exist. If the source file doesn't exist, there's not much the Python interpreter can do.

Comment: I am sure it is on the Desktop.. @NPE It is in front of me right now, and the image I posted is from the Desktop

Comment: @SandraK please add a screen shot output of `dir C:\Users\kkhalaf\Desktop\` command. Thanks.

Comment: Is `kkhalaf` your login name? (At a guess, is there an extra `k` in there?)

Comment: @NPE This is the problem: test.py.txt .. https://s30.postimg.org/wvoh81uxt/image.png Sorry but what should I do? I created a text file, and pasted the code in it. Then, renamed it to be `.py`

Comment: run it as `python.exe C:\Users\kkhalaf\Desktop\test.py.txt`

Comment: Run `ren C:\Users\kkhalaf\Desktop\test.py.txt C:\Users\kkhalaf\Desktop\test.py` to rename it.

Comment: `rename C:\Users\kkhalaf\Desktop\test.py.txt C:\Users\kkhalaf\Desktop\test.py` should rename that file and then retry your `python.exe ...` command. In the long run, configure windows to show file extensions so you can also manually replace them.

Comment: Thanks all. How can I show file extensions? @MSeifert

Comment: @SandraK probably best to google "display file extensions windows".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is saved as test.py.txt as shown in this image:

https://s30.postimg.org/wvoh81uxt/image.png

So you can either run the program as :

```
python.exe C:\Users\kkhalaf\Desktop\test.py.txt
```

OR rename the file to text.py and run the original command:

```
rename C:\Users\kkhalaf\Desktop\test.py.txt C:\Users\kkhalaf\Desktop\test.py

python.exe C:\Users\kkhalaf\Desktop\test.py
```

the reason you faced issue in the first place was because notepad saved the file in `text.py.txt` format instead of `test.py`

While doing save as you have to change `Save As Type` to `All Files (*.*)`

How to save file in .html format using a notepad. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_editors.asp

Comment: Hi and Thanks. If I want to rename, from which directory can I do that? https://s23.postimg.org/sd3xpg0e3/image.png
And usually when I want to start with python, how can I start to then skip the renaming phase?

Comment: you can rename from any directory as the rename function is given full path of the file. `C:\Users\kkhalaf\Desktop\test.py.txt` this is full path of the file

Comment: Which editor are you using to save python program ? Notepad ??

Comment: Well it pops an error saying it does not recognize the command (See the link in my comment). And I chose a txt file.

Comment: @SandraK use `rename` not `ren`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to execute this command from a shell that is open in the directory where the file exists, make sure your CMD/terminal is at the directory where you kept your .py file.

If not there, then go to the location you kept your file then Hold **shift** key + **right-click** and click "open command prompt here" then run this:

```
  python "test.py"
```

or:

```
py "test.py"
```

Comment: From which directory? Excuse me if this sounds noob

Comment: that would require that the desktop would be in the path. I don't think that's the case.

Comment: No, run in the directory you have your py file

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why do you think the file is in `C:\Python27` (his current working directory)?

Comment: your cwd is where-ever you execute the python command from ... assuming he is in the folder where his .py file is, this would indeed work... if you add that you need to execute this command from a shell that is open in the directory where the file exists i will +1

Comment: @SandraK check my answer."Which directory?" The directory you have the file.